# Are post edits allowed to change class and method names

Tags: discussion, edits

I am curious. The following edit was made to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4804477/revisions), where the editor changed the spelling of the methods and classes (not the case). The methods and classes follow the c# standard naming conventions, albeit the implied names where spelled wrong.

Are post edits allowed to change class and method names? How did this edit bring any value to the OP which was answered Jan 26 '11 at 12:23 (over 3 years ago) and has been up-voted 49 times.

Comment: At a minimum, the suggester should have rolled out the new names across all answers too. That is completely independent of the value or lack thereof of the edit itself.

Comment: How is this any different/less helpful than fixing spelling errors outside of code?

Comment: This is a useless edit and I wouldn't have approved it. It doesn't improve the question's clarity in any way and is very minor to begin with.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Why is the fact that it's code make its clarity *less* important.  I would think most programmers would recognize code clarity as a rather *important* thing to have.

Comment: presumably, the OP pasted his own code.  it is not how I would spell it, but I cant say it is spelled "wrong" because it is his code.  Since it is upvoted a lot and has been answered, the dubious spelling seems not to have been an issue for the last 3 years.

Comment: @Servy: to me, this doesn't affect clarity in any way. Self-defined methods and classes are abstract concepts in the first place so if it's named `DispatchGroup` or `DespatchGroup` doesn't make a difference for me (being a non-native English speaker might be a factor). I can see how a specific snippet relates to others by looking at the code; it's different when I want background information: I can only deduce that from the explanation given. If that's spelled incorrectly I don't have the context to fall back on. A minor error from `i` to `e` does not obstruct my reading.

Comment: You're in a world of hurt if the identifiers are in Spanish.  The compiler doesn't care what I call my identifiers in any case, so long as I name them consistently.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Changing code in a question (in any way) is always perilous.  You run the risk of inadvertently fixing the problem that the OP is asking about, or muddying the waters by changing its behavior.

Notice how the code in [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4804500/102937) no longer matches the question?

Comment: That's a good point about fixing the problem.

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion, that specific edit should have been rejected as too minor.  I don't see a misspelling of the Class/Method names as a large enough issue to worry about editing.  Misspelling of the text of the question or answer would be a different story, but class and method names just feel *different*.

But in general, if the edit is correcting a number of issues in the post that are actually worth fixing and they also correct the spelling in the Class/Method names, I don't see a problem there.

Answer (score 4):

I concurr that the specific edit was far **too minor**, and should thus be rejected.
Still, because it is *"source code"* that was edited, that makes it highly probable that the question is changed fundamentally or answers would no longer fit, so **radical change** would actually apply too!

It may be acceptable to correct only minor things, iff that's everything wrong with the post.
Also, in theory changing the code is acceptable, but in that case it behooves suggester/editer/reviewer to take extra care not to *destroy the question* and make sure to **roll out the changes to all answers as well**, because the final target is *making the site better*.